# Show that $(\log(n))! = \Omega(n^3)$

Tags: notation

I want to prove that  $(\log_{2}(n))! = \Omega(n^3)$.

I Think that $(\log_{2}(n))! = \Theta({\log_{2}(n)}^{\log_{2}(n)})$
But, I dont know how to continue.

Someone has an idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Does (log n)! even make sense? log 2 is not an integer, for instance.

Comment: $log_{2}(n) ! = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot ... \cdot log_{2}(n)$

Comment: If $n=2^k$, then $k!\approx k^ke^{-k}\sqrt{2\pi k}$. Compare with $n^3=2^{3k}$